# Problemas com .container-fluid e @media

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, layout-responsivo, front-end, grid

Sou iniciante no Bootstrap e estou utilizando o framework para um trabalho escolar.

Antigamente, eu estava utilizando a classe `.container` para deixar o conteúdo "junto", mas como não gostei do espaço em volta resolvi utilizar a `.container-fluid`. Até ai, tudo bem. Mas o que está acontecendo agora é que o documento está se redimensionando mais que o "normal do Bootstrap"  (< 767, 767 >= 991, 991 >= 1199, > 1200) e o `@media` do CSS está funcionando fora da medida que eu estou pedindo.

Seguem os códigos:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    $('#width').html('Documento: ' + $(document).width() + '<br/>\
                       Container: ' + $('.container-fluid').width());
  });
});
```

```css
@media (min-width: 624px) and (max-width: 1006px) {
  #dp-qtd {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1185px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
  #dp-qtd {
    display: none;
  }
}
#dashboard-perfil {
  /* div lateral do perfil */
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#dashboard-perfil p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#dp-dados {
  /* div com as informações do perfil */
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
}
#dp-foto {
  /* img - foto da dashboard */
  width: 103px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#dp-nome {
  /* p - nome do usuário */
  font-size: 14pt;
}
#dm-menu {
  /* ul com as opções de menu */
  padding: 5px 5px;
  list-style: none;
  background: white;
}
#dm-menu li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
#dm-menu li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
}
#dm-menu li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0; background: #DCDFE0;">
    <div id="width"></div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4" id="dashboard">

        <div id="dashboard-perfil">
          <div style="background: url('http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CncnrswWgAAHvWn.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: top; height: 160px;"
          id="dp-capa"></div>

          <div id="dp-dados">
            <a href="profile.php?username=<?= $username ?>">
       <img src="https://dyn.web.whatsapp.com/pp?t=l&u=5527996496870-1465520388%40g.us&i=1470673504&ref=0%40kEU%2BKEqxd4R7bNFuR%2FWAYDezQNqLMbdnNDOGd3o0UHlkONE9PZCeKtaK&tok=0%40iW8Ka0H%2FSw3Gc3wy5ZmTB7E0UrHgMrt%2FkbGsbVVmqp5Qes1ZIyaFxW6CmY%2FyECwAPZdc2Pe39PFlOQ%3D%3D" alt="Foto de perfil de <?= $dados['nome']?>" id="dp-foto">
      </a>
            <p id="dp-nome">
              BS
            </p>

            <ul id="dp-qtd">
              <li>
                teste
              </li>

              <li>
                teste
              </li>

              <li>
                teste
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-5" id="feed" style="background-color: navy">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae mi accumsan, pulvinar lorem ut, laoreet arcu. Ut iaculis ipsum nec neque pharetra, hendrerit lacinia sem sollicitudin. Pellentesque vulputate sem eu ipsum semper tempus. Duis velit
          nisi, pharetra ut dictum ut, molestie et nisl. Mauris rhoncus, ipsum ac condimentum mattis, turpis risus eleifend libero, et ultrices magna neque non nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec hendrerit neque eu nulla tincidunt, sed ullamcorper
          magna placerat. Nulla quis augue nibh. Vivamus suscipit elementum porttitor. Mauris auctor porta ipsum at tincidunt. Maecenas vitae faucibus nibh. Cras semper, ex et faucibus sollicitudin, dolor sapien fringilla urna, sit amet auctor turpis
          quam non justo. Praesent blandit leo diam, at faucibus nunc pellentesque eu. Vivamus a sapien dignissim, posuere mi sed, rutrum libero. Nulla gravida, neque eu ullamcorper egestas, est massa eleifend quam, suscipit interdum leo magna vitae arcu.</p>
        <p>Proin maximus interdum arcu vitae congue. Quisque scelerisque, enim id bibendum finibus, orci justo tincidunt metus, porta luctus turpis augue vulputate turpis. Cras in dui eu eros ultricies semper. Aliquam ut finibus tellus, et laoreet diam.
          Sed purus lacus, elementum id libero eget, tempus dictum nisl. In euismod fringilla consectetur. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque est felis, fringilla in neque a, maximus ultricies ante. Vestibulum euismod interdum imperdiet. Phasellus
          rutrum quam ut lacus lobortis feugiat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur molestie libero nec consequat fermentum. Nulla quis dui lacus. Vivamus vitae nisi cursus, ultrices orci et, dignissim ante. Vivamus non velit tellus.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" style="background-color: #b90000">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae mi accumsan, pulvinar lorem ut, laoreet arcu. Ut iaculis ipsum nec neque pharetra, hendrerit lacinia sem sollicitudin. Pellentesque vulputate sem eu ipsum semper tempus. Duis velit
          nisi, pharetra ut dictum ut, molestie et nisl. Mauris rhoncus, ipsum ac condimentum mattis, turpis risus eleifend libero, et ultrices magna neque non nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec hendrerit neque eu nulla tincidunt, sed ullamcorper
          magna placerat. Nulla quis augue nibh. Vivamus suscipit elementum porttitor. Mauris auctor porta ipsum at tincidunt. Maecenas vitae faucibus nibh. Cras semper, ex et faucibus sollicitudin, dolor sapien fringilla urna, sit amet auctor turpis
          quam non justo. Praesent blandit leo diam, at faucibus nunc pellentesque eu. Vivamus a sapien dignissim, posuere mi sed, rutrum libero. Nulla gravida, neque eu ullamcorper egestas, est massa eleifend quam, suscipit interdum leo magna vitae arcu.</p>
        <p>Proin maximus interdum arcu vitae congue. Quisque scelerisque, enim id bibendum finibus, orci justo tincidunt metus, porta luctus turpis augue vulputate turpis. Cras in dui eu eros ultricies semper. Aliquam ut finibus tellus, et laoreet diam.
          Sed purus lacus, elementum id libero eget, tempus dictum nisl. In euismod fringilla consectetur. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque est felis, fringilla in neque a, maximus ultricies ante. Vestibulum euismod interdum imperdiet. Phasellus
          rutrum quam ut lacus lobortis feugiat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur molestie libero nec consequat fermentum. Nulla quis dui lacus. Vivamus vitae nisi cursus, ultrices orci et, dignissim ante. Vivamus non velit tellus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Como podem ver, em algumas situações o `@media` funciona e em outras não. Se colocarem em tela cheia, também verão o problema do redimensionamento. Aqui no meu computador ele faz o que peço no `@media` com 15px de diferença (então, se peço pra fazer aos 1510px, ele faz aos 1495px).

O que estou fazendo de errado?

**EDIT:**
Percebi que está funcionando corretamente enquanto está responsivo. Mas quando passa de 767px, ao invés do tamanho do documento ser de 768px, ele volta 15px e fica com 753px.

Comment: Aqui parece está a funcionar direito, podes explicar melhor?

Comment: Eu acho que esses 15px de que fala têm a haver com as class `col-...` que por defAULT vêm com `15px` de padding `left/right`

Comment: @JorgeB., o que está acontecendo são dois problemas:
1. A classe .container-fluid está fazendo o resize várias vezes, além do que já é conhecido, supus que fosse por conta das classes col-sm, lg, e etc... mas não tenho certeza.
2. O media está funcionando com medidas erradas, exemplo no código, é que o document está com 623px, mas a propriedade de tirar a ul de teste a partir dos 624px funcionou.

Aqui no meu código, está dando um diferencial de 15px para as medidas que eu defini no media.

Comment: @Miguel, testei sem retirar os 15px dos padding-left e right e mesmo assim, não funcionou. O que mudou é que agora, a diferença passou de 15px para 45px (então adicionou os pixels do padding).

Comment: Ha sim, estou a perceber

Comment: @MatheusSantos mas se não me engano, esse é o comportamento do ´content-fluid`. Quando tiver mais um bocadinho de tempo eu testo isso...

Comment: Já agora evite saudações e agradecimentos, veja [ask].

Comment: @MatheusSantos aqui tem sempre o mesmo tamanho até 1920px

Comment: @MatheusSantos ora vê http://i.stack.imgur.com/UkNXZ.png

Comment: @JorgeB. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e por tentar resolver, analisei mais a fundo e vi que o problema era na função que pegava o tamanho, porque estava dando problema com a barra de scroll. Mancada de iniciante rsrs
Mas muitíssimo obrigado!